# Detect if user is typing an email or number with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I detect if a user is typing a phone number or email address as the user typing from the first three inputs.

I am creating  a login in system for my company

I need this to format the users phone number when is user is typing automatically.

PS:I already know how to do the formatting in the form I want

WORTHY NOTE: emails could also come in 44566@example.com or 334-333@example.com how can I detect.

**Is it possible**

Lets say I have

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone number or Email" id="number_or_email" onkeyup="fire_after_first_three()">

function fire_after_first_three(){
//do number formatting on the go or ignore user input if email
}
```

Where the USER can either use Phone Number or Email address to login.

The expected input from the user is: for phone number XXXXXXXXXXX which I do format to XXX-XXXX-XXXX or email xxx@example.com which is checked at the backend.

I need to know user input, so that I can format the phone number on fly if the user decides to use phone number to log in.

Comment: Since there's a significant amount of overlap between the acceptable character pattern for a phone number and the [local-part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) of an email address, there's a non-zero chance that you'll get it wrong. I could conceivably have the email address `8008675309@email.com`, or even `800-867-5309@email.com`.

Comment: @somewhatsapient You are very correct, what is the best approach.

Comment: is this strictly for your company's internal uses, and are there any rules in place for how the email address is formatted? For example, if I'm John Smith, would my email be `jsmith@company.com` or `johnsmith@company.com` etc?

Comment: @somewhatsapient Thanks for your answer, its not for internal use, its for an e-commerce website we are developing.

Comment: @somewhatsapient emails could come in any format as you said, just have to guess and attach functions to run if phone number is being typed to do the formatting or ignore if email

Comment: @Shasha why are you checking after only 3 digits? If the input wasn't entirely numeric/didn't meet the phone criteria, then check for the `@'symbol/email format (or vice versa)- that would be one approach - or let user select option box of how they want to log in -  that would allow you check for the appropriate format - that would be another  - don't understand the 3 digit approach?

Comment: @rachelgallen Thank you for your answer, ok, did not think in that direction, could a code epansion.

Comment: In the function executing onkeypress, I would do the following:
Check whether the chars typed in is a number or NaN.
If it's a number, always assume it's just that until the end.
As soon as the first non numerical character is typed, switch to email.
To ensure you are remembering what the user typed. capture their input in a variable accessible to the function. You will always use this value to update the string displayed to work as a mask for the input.

Comment: @marius Thank you for your answer, highly appreciated, could i get a fiddle. a simple one, please.

Comment: @Shasha  bear in mind that someone may type a letter instead of a number in error while typing in their phone number.

Comment: Better off letting user tell you by some other control which they are entering

Comment: You can use some input mask. that would help you and easy for the users too. https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the length of the phone no as `11`. You can validate the after 3 input as I've started as soon as user start inserting input.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function validateOnlyNumbers(phone) {
  return phone.match(/^\d+$/);
}

const input = document.querySelector("input");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");

input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  const value = e.target.value;

  if (validateOnlyNumbers(value)) {
    if (value.length === 11) {
      h1.textContent = "Phone Number"
      // Format input acc to phone no
    } else {
      h1.textContent = "could be Phone Number"
    }
  } else {
    if (validateEmail(value)) {
      h1.textContent = "Email"
      // Format input acc to Email
    } else {
      h1.textContent = "could be Email"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<h1></h1>
```